# How to get only time value (H:M:S) and compare it in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to control devices (module Raspberry Pi) in a certain time period. I make a PHP web to config time value in database mysql. Then I get time from database to compare with time in system (real time clock). If system time is in between time in mysql => led on.

Here is my table(name: time) in mysql:

```
start_time                      stop_time
07:00:00 (Type: time)           08:00:00 (Type:time)
```

And here is my code control device:

```
import MySQLdb
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from datetime import date
import time
db_local = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","luan_van")
with db_local:
      cur = db_local.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
      cur.execute("SELECT * FROM time")
      rows = cur.fetchall()
      start = 0
      stop = 0
      for row in rows:
          start = row['start_time']
          stop = row ['stop_time']
tg = strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
if( start < tg < stop):
     GPIO.output(12, True)
```

It error "can't compare datetime.timedelta to str".
How can I get system time value format "H:M:S"?
Thank for help.

Comment: *"How can I get system time value format "H:M:S"?"* - you already have that, `strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `start` and `stop` objects are *`datetime.timedelta`* objects; these model *time durations*, not the time of day. You have two options here:

1. Produce another `timedelta` to represent the current time, as a delta since midnight
2. Convert the start and stop values to actual time-of-day values

You can produce a `timedelta` for 'now' with:

```
import datetime

midnight = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.min)
time_since_midnight = datetime.datetime.now() - midnight
```

then compare that with your start and stop:

```
if start < time_since_midnight < stop:
```

In the other direction, converting the start and stop timedeltas to `datetime.datetime` objects means you need to *add* them to the `midnight` object:

```
import datetime

midnight = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.min)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
if (midnight + start) < now < (midnight + stop):
```

A variation on the latter could be to just use the `.time()` components and ignore the date portion, but since you already are basing all dates on 'today' that won't make a difference here.